# Not Able to Connect to Password-protected MongoDB Server/DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

After successfully testing my Node app against a local mongoDB db, I am now trying to connect to our server db - which, unlike my local mongoDB, is user and password protected.

I am running into issues while trying the connection to the server. Specifically, I am getting this error:

> MongoError: MongoClient must be connected before calling
>   MongoClient.prototype.db

The creds I'm trying look something like this:

```
{
  "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://myuser:mypassword@someurl.com:27017?authSource=admin",
  "MONGO_DATABASE": "bta",
  "MONGO_COLLECTION": "jobs"
}
```

And here is my connection code:

```
const config = require('./configuration');
const url = config.get('MONGO_URL');
const dbName = config.get('MONGO_DATABASE');

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(url);

async function getJobDetails() {
  client.connect(async function () {
    try {
      const db = await client.db(dbName);
      // do stuff
     });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was and was able to get it to connect. The issue was that the site is secure, so I had to add `ssl=true` to the url connection string:

```
const url = 'mongodb://user:password@someurl.com:27017/bta?ssl=true&authSource=admin';
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

mongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(client_err, client) {
    if (client != null) {
        var client_db = client.db(dbName);
    }
    client.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As MongoDB.
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/tutorials/connect/

**And please Try double checking DB on the server if it has the right config.**

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL with password example
const url = 'mongodb://user:password@address:27017?readPreference=primary&authSource=admin';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function(err) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  client.close();
});
```

This works for both valid localhost/server url

[image: Checking code]

Comment: Set this up as a separate file and tried running it. Got the exact same error: `MongoError: MongoClient must be connected before calling MongoClient.prototype.db`

Comment: Try logging the `err` returned in the callback.

Comment: ECONNREFUSED apparently this error came from the server.

Comment: Meaning, I guess, that I got as far as the server, but the credentials were refused? Sound right?

Comment: So, all that is to say, that's the same error I got with my initial code. So the issue must be with credentials, but not with the code I'm using to connect.